# Prove that Frobenius matrix norm is compatible with the vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Show that, the Frobenius matrix norm $||.||_F$ is compatible or consistent with a vector norm $||.||_2$ , that is, $||Ax||_2 \leq ||A||_F ||x||_2, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Where $||A||_F = \sqrt{ \sum_{i,j=1}^N |a_{ij}|^2} $

Comment: If the vector space $X$ is of finite dimension,then all norms are equivalent.[here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/course/math560_fall2011/norm_equiv.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(Ax)_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}x_j$, hence $$\|Ax\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}x_j)^2$$
But $(\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}x_j)^2\leq (\sum_{j=1}^n{a_{i,j}^2})(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2)=(\sum_{j=1}^n{a_{i,j}^2})\|x\|_2^2$
We get 
$$\|Ax\|_2^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}^2\|x\|_2^2=\|A\|_F^2\|x\|_2^2$$
i.e $$\|Ax\|_2\leq \|A\|_F\|x\|_2 $$